# Android Studio не читает аннотации

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я хочу сделать Веб-сервис. На ПК запускается сам сервис, а андроид телефон используется как клиент В Intellij IDEA все работает, в Android Studio ругается на аннотации:WebService, SOAPBinding, WebMethod. 
Вот код:

```
    import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.example.maxim.project_r.mWebService")
public class WebServiceImpl implements mWebService {
    @Override
    public String getHelloString(String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

---

```
import android.app.Service;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class WebServiceClient {
    public static void connect_ws() throws MalformedURLException {
        try{
            URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.90:1986/wss/hello?wsdl");

            QName qname = new QName("http://ws.mnolimp.ru/", "WebServiceImplService");

            Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
            mWebService hello = service.getPort(mWebService.class);

            System.out.println(hello.getHelloString("Service"));
        }catch (WebServiceException e){
            System.out.println("Web Service not available");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC)
public interface mWebService {
    @WebMethod
    public String getHelloString(String name);
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста, я новичок в Андроид и Веб технологиях

Comment: Еще ругается на импорты в классе WebServiceImpl и mWebService

Comment: если ругается на импорты и аннотации, значит соответствующих веток нет в android sdk

Comment: То есть надо просто найти нужный мне Android SDK?

Comment: Нет такого  Android SDK - Вам нужно добавить в зависимости (`dependencies`) соответствующие библиотеки, если они вообще существуют самостоятельно (а не только в составе `Java EE SDK`) и совместимы с Андроидом. Иначе искать совместимую альтернативу по вкусу.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое